# SVG sprite on stack don't appear on Safarii

Tags: css, svg, safari, icons, sprite

I created SVG sprite, where icons are on stack and displayed when targeting chosen ID. It works ok, but I don't know why, icons not appear on Safari, I can't find explanation in case when you're using SVG as a background. Is any one familiar with this problem?

**SVG**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="icon" class="icon" version="1.1">
<defs>
    <style>
        svg .icon {
        display: none;
        }

        svg .icon:target {
        display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</defs>

<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g id="icon-instagram" class="icon" fill="#fff">
        <path fill-rule="nonzero"
              d="M17.2808471,0 L6.58644706,0 C2.95468235,0 0,2.95482353 0,6.58658824 L0,17.2809882 C0,20.9128941 2.95468235,23.8675765 6.58644706,23.8675765 L17.2808471,23.8675765 C20.9128941,23.8675765 23.8675765,20.9127529 23.8675765,17.2809882 L23.8675765,6.58658824 C23.8677176,2.95482353 20.9128941,0 17.2808471,0 Z M21.7500706,17.2809882 C21.7500706,19.7452235 19.7452235,21.7499294 17.2809882,21.7499294 L6.58644706,21.7499294 C4.12235294,21.7500706 2.11764706,19.7452235 2.11764706,17.2809882 L2.11764706,6.58658824 C2.11764706,4.12249412 4.12235294,2.11764706 6.58644706,2.11764706 L17.2808471,2.11764706 C19.7450824,2.11764706 21.7499294,4.12249412 21.7499294,6.58658824 L21.7499294,17.2809882 L21.7500706,17.2809882 Z"/>
        <path fill-rule="nonzero"
              d="M11.9337882 5.784C8.54258824 5.784 5.78371765 8.54287059 5.78371765 11.9340706 5.78371765 15.3251294 8.54258824 18.0838588 11.9337882 18.0838588 15.3249882 18.0838588 18.0838588 15.3251294 18.0838588 11.9340706 18.0838588 8.54287059 15.3249882 5.784 11.9337882 5.784zM11.9337882 15.9660706C9.7104 15.9660706 7.90136471 14.1573176 7.90136471 11.9339294 7.90136471 9.7104 9.71025882 7.90150588 11.9337882 7.90150588 14.1573176 7.90150588 15.9662118 9.7104 15.9662118 11.9339294 15.9662118 14.1573176 14.1571765 15.9660706 11.9337882 15.9660706zM18.3417882 3.98837647C17.9337882 3.98837647 17.5329882 4.15355294 17.2448471 4.44296471 16.9552941 4.73096471 16.7888471 5.13190588 16.7888471 5.54131765 16.7888471 5.94945882 16.9554353 6.35025882 17.2448471 6.63967059 17.5328471 6.92767059 17.9337882 7.09425882 18.3417882 7.09425882 18.7512 7.09425882 19.1507294 6.92767059 19.4401412 6.63967059 19.7295529 6.35025882 19.8947294 5.94931765 19.8947294 5.54131765 19.8947294 5.13190588 19.7295529 4.73096471 19.4401412 4.44296471 19.1521412 4.15355294 18.7512 3.98837647 18.3417882 3.98837647z"/>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g id="icon-facebook" class="icon" fill="#fff">
        <path d="M2.93630055,4.93539414 L2.93630055,8.17223941 L0.564884222,8.17223941 L0.564884222,12.1302664 L2.93630055,12.1302664 L2.93630055,23.8921306 L7.80769311,23.8921306 L7.80769311,12.1305943 L11.0766237,12.1305943 C11.0766237,12.1305943 11.3827734,10.2327507 11.5311748,8.15764524 L7.82611347,8.15764524 L7.82611347,5.45138285 C7.82611347,5.04690017 8.35724295,4.50281631 8.88219587,4.50281631 L11.5363128,4.50281631 L11.5363128,0.382285714 L7.92761676,0.382285714 C2.81588497,0.382012415 2.93630055,4.34397487 2.93630055,4.93539414 Z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-instagram {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background: url("../svg/viva-sprite.svg#icon-instagram") no-repeat;
}
.icon-facebook {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background: url("../svg/viva-sprite.svg#icon-facebook") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I have tried to define width and height particular svg, but still not working... :(

Comment: sorry, just to clarify: did you add width/height to your svg or in your css?

Comment: yes, but it not helps :/

Comment: Fragment identifiers are not supported by safari - http://caniuse.com/svg-fragment/embed/description you need a javascript fallback. Further reading: https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/

Comment: Thanks for that @Ruskin!

Comment: no worries ... also note that Firefox's behaviour is different from Chrome ... it sometimes needs the full URI of the fragment, not just the hash #id